# PHPMyAdmin CSV Import Encoding UTF8 Problem

Tags: sql, csv, encoding, phpmyadmin, csv-import

I want to import a simple CSV. In my SQL all fields and the table self has the `utf8_general_ci` encoding. The import is successful but the fields which contain vowel mutations stops at this point.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you give a sample record or field?

Comment: @benc have it already thank you. I made in Notepad++ always encode utf8 instead of convert to utf8